# Can congressional committees publish phone records as part of their report?

Tags: united-states, congress

The [US House Intelligence committee](https://www.cnn.com/2019/12/03/politics/house-intelligence-committee-report/index.html) released their report this week detailing the evidence they believe supports the case for impeaching Donald Trump.

In the report are a bunch of phone records. I understand the records were subpoenaed from AT&T as part of the investigation.

Are there any rules which govern the release of phone record information to the public? As was done in intelligence report. or are there privacy laws which govern phone records in general?

Answer (score 2):

Congressmen are immune from prosecution for anything they read into the record.  It's an established practice (enshrined in law and confirmed by the Court) that, in order to allow maximum latitude in their debates, Congressmen are immune both to criminal prosecution and to civil lawsuits for anything they utter during their speaking time in Congress.

Comment: okay, but the phone records weren't uttered or vocalized into the public record. Nobody knew about the records until the report came out. 

So does this apply to reports committees issue?

Comment: @Troyd that's a different question.  If they were entered into classified record, then the question is whether private information entered into classified records has special protections.  You may want to ask that question separately.

Comment: i'm confused, my original question specifically references the report they released, not any vocalization

Comment: @Troyd that's a fair point.  But their report had to be based on evidence which they received.  They either received it in an open hearing or in a closed (possibly classified) hearing.  Even if it wasn't a (vocal) utterance, it was *submitted into the record*.

Comment: @Troyd another interesting question may whether they are protected from liability if they lie in their reports.  If they are protected, then the report can be performance art.